What would make my sunflower leaves as they’re growing start to shrivel up and become almost deformed?
The plant seems fine, but now the leaves almost look, wrinkled as they’re growing out and look like they are not taking true shape the edges have a bit of black on them, where they are wrinkled and creased. Any help would be appreciated.

A picture or two would help.
